# how to specify the unzip target directory

Tags: linux, zip

Is there an option on linux zip command such that I can hard code the target directory it unzips into. For example, I would like to zip ./mydir files into myzipfile.zip but I want the unzip command to create a specific directory "projx" and expand the files which were under ./mydir to it.

```
zip -r myzipfile.zip mydir (-option to expand into 'projx' when unzipped? )
```

Comment: On Unix: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12686/unzip-to-a-specific-folder

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no such option, at least not for Info-ZIP. You have to create a directory *projx* yourself, move/copy your files into it and then pass it to `zip`.

If the directory already exists then just pass option `-d` to `unzip` to specify the target directory for extraction.

Answer (score 4):

To do that there is an another way. You can flatted the entire contents of the zip file using following method. Target directory is "***projx***" and execute following command.

```
cd /projx && unzip -j /path/to/myzipfile.zip
```

Option ***-j*** is called "junk paths" and just dumps each file into the current directory instead of extracting any directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a specific command line option, but you can use the following commands to reach you goal:

```
ln -s mydir projx
zip -r myzipfile.zip projx
rm projx
```

The first command creates a symbolic link, so that you can access the files in `mydir` also via `projx`. Then using `Info-ZIP` (tested with version 2.31) the symbolic link is dereferenced (this is the default, unless you specify `-y`) and the files are stored recursively:

```
adding: projx/ (stored 0%)
adding: projx/foo.1 (deflated 23%)
adding: projx/bar.2 (deflated 73%)
...
```

You see, the folder name is stored in the file, too -- so upon extraction the directory `projx` is created.

However, I can't think of a possibility to store absolute paths, but this is a bad idea anyway.

Comment: Absolute path only works on MacOS by specifying option `-jj`. On other operating systems only option `-j` is supported (and `-jj` is interpreted as `-j`) which removes any leading path and thus leading to the opposite (a very clever design...).